# How can I build Android apps using an Android phone?

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle, arm64

I'm trying to build normal Android apps on an Android phone. Yes, I know most people use an x86_64 system, or a Mac. But I want to build an app using my phone because I live off the grid and using a phone (and ARM processor) is much more energy efficient than a desktop or laptop. I would have to burn gasoline to generate power for a laptop, and I want to avoid doing that.

I have an Android project that requires Java 8, Platform 26 or higher, and Gradle. (https://github.com/vanilla-music/vanilla)

I've seen some projects like Termux with BuildAPKs build sample APKs, but they don't need Gradle. So I set up a Debian Buster chroot, but the software is old (Gradle 4.4.1). With LinuxDeploy on a rooted phone I can run various different arm-based distros. So the problem really boils down to: How can I build apps on an arm64 machine?

**2022 UPDATE**

Inspired by this fantastic article I decided to try again:
https://www.hanshq.net/command-line-android.html

With a 4GB LinuxDeploy image of Debian 11 Bullseye, I was able to install build tools, platform tools, etc (see gitlab link below for exact setup). And with a tip from https://gitlab.com/fdroid/sdkmanager/-/issues/8 I was able to get past license agreements. But then when I run `gradle build`, gradle downloads files for x86_64, and then of course the build fails.

So now I'm wondering: Why is gradle specifically requesting those build tools? How can I stop it from doing that?

Comment: I've gotten a lot of dirty looks by asking this question, but it's a fundamentally great question. Unfortunately, Google has created a culture of "no, you can't do that with your phone because *we say so*". So my development sensibilities have led me to be interested in the Pine Phone. I understand Google's greedy self-interested nature, but what I don't understand is the negative response from the development community for asking such a question. And besides, I'm not even trying to develop a whole app. I'm just trying to fix up an app that I already use.

Comment: this kind of question lead to answer based on opinions instead facts and are therefore considered as off-topic here on SO

Answer (score 0):

You have to try using **AIDE- IDE for Android Java C++** on https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui

Comment: I've tried apps like this. At best they can build a sample APK, but not anything useful

Answer (score 0):

I've built fairly functional apps with this app: https://github.com/tyron12233/CodeAssist. It is a bit buggy but it supports Androidx and constraintlayout out of the box. Note that it is not as feature rich as Android Studio unfortunately.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34041534)

Comment: as I pointed out on another comment in the original question the problem is the question itself..